# python not iterating through the rest of array

Tags: python

I have a few loops nested into each other and I'll post the relevant code then explain:

```
ANN = ['array','of','fourteen','people']
COUNT = 14

for i in range(COUNT):
    CNT = i
    print CNT
    for i in ANN:
        ANNOTATOR = i
        for row in PRGREADER:
            print row
            if (ANNOTATOR in row[2]) and (WEEK in row[3]):
                if PRGFILE.strip('.csv') not in ANNODAT[CNT][0]:
                    ANNODAT[CNT][0].append(PRGFILE.strip('.csv'))
```

This chunk of code is supposed to read a csv file(read into PRGREADER), check and see if the current value of ANN and a week number are on that row. If they are, it takes the name of the file and stores it in an array.

I've narrowed it down to realizing it iterates through COUNT, it iterates through ANN, but after that it only performs the rest of this code on the first iteration through ANN and no one else. Why is this not performing the rest of the nested code after the first iteration of ANN?

*edit* adding the creation of PRGREADER

```
for filename in os.listdir('progress/'):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        PRGFILES.append(filename)


for i in PRGFILES:
    PRGFILE = i
    with open('./progress/' + PRGFILE,'rb') as PROGRESS:
        PROGRESS = [element.upper() for element in PROGRESS]
        PRGREADER = csv.reader(PROGRESS, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '|')
```

Comment: though it doesn't perform the rest of the code on each iteration of ANN, it does continue to iterate through ANN, COUNT, and opens the multiple files it's built to handle. The only thing not working is it's not performing the append chunk for the other iterations of ANN.

Comment: You are probably hiding useful information from yourself with the catchall exception. Also `PRGFILE.strip` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Is `PRGREADER` a file object? File objects can only be iterated through once, unless you `seek` back to the beginning after reading.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy how would I get the useful information if I removed except? Also what should I use for removing the extension and storing the name as a string in an array? The filename has multiple purposes within the code and strip does what I need it to do, but I'm always open to learning the more correct/accurate way to do something.

Comment: First of all, what thing inside the try to you think will fail? I think that only bugs in your code will throw exceptions at that point. If there is some reason for the try, then you should at least print the message of the error that you are ignoring to aid in this debugging.

Comment: wait, why was this downvoted?

Comment: @Joonazan in its current state, nothing. I've rewritten this a few times and kept some parts/removed others. That part I can do without. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: You should read the docs for [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) It's not suitable for trimming the extension. (ie. it's actually wrong). Then look up the `os.path` module

Comment: @JohnLaRooy is that part of the reason I'm having the issue?

Comment: @saniboy You shouldn't use a catch all exception then throw away the error because any problems that come up will be caught and thrown out, and you'll never know they happened. Only catch errors that you expect to happen and can deal with. Otherwise you should let it fail, or at the very least log the exception so you know something went wrong.

Comment: @saniboy, probably not causing your problem now, but it's a nice gotcha for later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue has to do with iterating over the same `csv.reader` object several times. A `reader` object is an iterator, so after you've iterated over it once, you won't get any more results trying to iterate more, since it's been exhausted. You either need to recreate your reader each time through the loop, or reorganize your code so that that you don't need to iterate on it several times (for instance, making it the outer loop rather than the inner one).

There are a number of other issues with your code that you may also want to change. For instance, you repeatedly use `for i in something`, then immediately bind some other name to `i`. You should simply put that other name directly into the loop (e.g. `for CNT in range(...)`). I'd also suggest following a better variable name style, such as `lower_case_with_underscores` for normal variables and reserving `ALL_CAPITALS` for constants (`CapitalizedNames` is also conventional for the names of classes, but you don't seem to have any of those).

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of this and it's exactly what I needed to push forward.